# Outputting mac address as standard format in mysql

Tags: mysql, format, hex, mac-address

After reading some research, I understand that mac addresses stored in mysql should be stored as `BIG INT`.  Is there an easy way to output the mac's in the standard hex form:  `ab:23:a4:23:54:33` when using a `SELECT` statement?

I know I can use `hex()` to convert format to hexadecimal, but i'd like the full 6 bytes and colons.  thanks.

Something like:

`SELECT hex(macAddress) from <table>;`

Answer (score 3):

if you have your macAddress stored as a string you can use the following text conversion.

```
SELECT
    mac, concat(left(mac,2), ":",substring(mac,3,2), ":" , substring(mac,5,2),
     ":",substring(mac,7,2), ":",substring(mac,9,2), ":", 
    right(mac,2)) as mac_colons 
FROM mac_table;
```

Comment: Thank you, I have been looking for this for 5 hour

Answer (score 0):

A little bit better:

```
SELECT
  mac, CONCAT_WS(':',left(mac,2), substring(mac,3,2), substring(mac,5,2),
   substring(mac,7,2), substring(mac,9,2), right(mac,2)) as mac_colons 
FROM mac_table;
```